# While loop through XPathNodeIterator not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath, xpathnodeiterator

I have an `XPathNodeIterator` named **_xpCategories** which holds a data like this

```
        <root>
      <category numberofproducts="0">
        <id>hoved</id>
        <url>/products/hovednavigation</url>
        <name>HOVEDNAVIGATION</name>
        <category numberofproducts="0">
          <id>embalfors</id>
          <url>/products/emballage-og-forsendelse</url>
          <name>Emballage og forsendelse</name>
          <category numberofproducts="0">
            <id>gaveindpak</id>
            <url>/products/gaveindpakning</url>
            <name>Gaveindpakning</name>
            <category numberofproducts="3">
              <id>cellofan</id>
              <url>/products/cellofan</url>
              <name>Cellofan</name>
            </category>
            <category numberofproducts="30">
              <id>gavebånd</id>
              <url>/products/gavebaand</url>
              <name>Gavebånd</name>
            </category>
          </category>
          <category numberofproducts="0">
            <id>kuvkonv</id>
            <url>/products/kuverter-og-konvolutter</url>
            <name>Kuverter og konvolutter</name>
          </category>
          </category>
      </category>
</root>
```

I want to traverse through each categories in this **xml** and print **id** of each one.
I had done some code like this.

```
 while (_xpCategories.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_xpCategories.Current.SelectSingleNode("id"));

    }
```

But this loop only works one ,only first category id is getting,then it exist the loop.Can any one point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: looks to me like your xml is wrong. you have category within category, etc. the loop you have is just iterating over 1 node which is why it only loops once.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel Is there any way to loop through whole document?

Comment: if you want to do that you wouldn't use `XPath`. However you should be able to adjust the `XPath` query you are doing to select all `Categories`

Can you should the `XPath` you are using to select all categories?

Comment: @SecretSquirrel I haven't completely understood your solution.Can you add it as an answer her so that I can get in to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to modify your `XPath` expression to select all the categories within your document no matter where they are within the document, as you have 1 parent category with child categories and then child categories within those child categories.

`/root/category` - this will just select the parent category node (1 node) with many child nodes.

`//category` - this should select all categories within the XML document no matter where they appear.

take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator.aspx) for more help

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XPathNavigator with XPathNodeIterator like this

(A modified example [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnodeiterator.movenext.aspx))

```
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("yourxml.xml");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

XPathNodeIterator _xpCategories = navigator.Select("//category");
_xpCategories.MoveNext();

while (nodesText.MoveNext())
    Console.WriteLine(nodesText.Current.Value);
```

Comment: I am fetching the XML from a third party dll ,I dn't have any control over it ,They are just providing me an XPathNodeIterator to work on,So its impossible to code like XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("yourxml.xml");

Comment: How do you populate _xpCategories with your Json? Can you post some more code?